# Requirement of satisfying $xABy=zBy$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that there are $1 \times n$ vectors $x$ and $z$, $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, $n \times 1$ vector $y$.

If these are to satisfy $xABy=zBy$, what would be the relationship between these matrices and vectors?

Comment: For real matrices and vectors, $xABy=zBy$ means $z$ lies inside the sum of the row space of $A$ and the orthogonal complement of $By$, but I guess this kind of reformulation is not what you want.

Comment: In the case everything is real (and, *mutatis mutandis*, in the case everything is complex) $xABy = zBy$ if and only if $(z - xA)By = 0$, if and only if $z^T - A^T x^T \in y^\perp$, so user1551's observation is really all there is to say.